# VLC media player show mouse cursor on the top of the video

Tags: linux, video, mouse, vlc-media-player, debian-wheezy

I'm using **VLC media 2.03** player on **Debian Weezy**. I want mouse cursor to visible on the top of the video. Currently I cannot see the cursor inside video play when it entered from left or right.When cursor entered from bottom it shows on the video just only about 2 seconds. I want cursor to display always on top.

I tried almost all the options by i cannot get to work on my preference. I hope someone may have a solution.

Comment: not sure about Debian specifically, but VLC by default only shows the cursor when it's moving, then after a few seconds, it fades

Comment: Ya I can live with that if it works as you said. But in Debian It's not showing even when moving horizontally.

Comment: I am having a same problem on linux mint 18

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš I'm still not sure why this happened. It didn't solve however. I moved to archlinux and Centos, so I've never faced that again. Have you tried re-installing VLC or do a system upgrade?

Comment: Yes I tried both

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš Please check the answer I posted, which might work for you. Good luck !

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš if that's not helping, I suggest updating Mint repositories as where you can upgrade VLC to more latest reliable version.

Answer (score 0):

[In ubuntu launchpad this is listed as an unassigned confirmed bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vlc/+bug/1601981)

**But as a workaround following method is reported to be working;**

*In a terminal , enter the following command;*

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

*As soon as this command is applied, cursor will be visible again like it should have been. No need for a restart.*

(Note: You can do this through **dconf** as well.)

[Originally got this solution from here](https://itsfoss.com/invisible-mouse-cursor-ubuntu-1310/)